# Eclipse Expressions View shows unreadable strings

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using POI API to read from a Excel. When debugging, Eclipse Expressions View shows `unreadable values`, like `??????`.In fact, they're **Chinese or Japanese characters**. After copying and pasting to an editor, these strings become **readable**.

Debugging at one breakpoint, they're readable, but at another breakpoint, they become unreadable.

**Readable**:
[image]

**Unreadable**:
[image]

Why do I get these values unreadable?
How could I configure to make these values readable?

Comment: You'll need to add some screen shots of what you're talking about.

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple test and found `????` unreadable strings. Maybe the cause is Eclipse itself when characters are too many.

[image]